# Compare elements in lists on 1 column rows and assign unique values in new column, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compare elements in lists in 1 column and assign unique values that are on no other row in new column in the same Pandas df:

Int.:

```
data = {'object_1':[1, 3, 4, 5, 77],
'object_2':[1, 5, 100, 3, 4],
"object_3": [1, 3, 4, 5, 5],
"object_4": [1, 3, 5, 47, 48]}
```

Out.:

```
data = {'object_1':[1, 3, 4, 5, 77],
'object_2':[1, 5, 100, 3, 4],
"object_3": [1, 3, 4, 5, 5],
"object_4": [1, 3, 5, 47, 48],
"unique_values": [[77], [100], [None], [47,48]],
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This cannot be a pandas dataframe because the lists are of different lengths. They could of course be filled out with NaN or such values.

Comment: You are right, my bad. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isin` and `stack`:

```
data['unique_values'] = ([df.loc[~df[col].isin(df.set_index(col).stack()), col].tolist()
                   for col in df.columns])
```

data:

```
{'object_1': [1, 3, 4, 5, 77],
 'object_2': [1, 5, 100, 3, 4],
 'object_3': [1, 3, 4, 5, 5],
 'object_4': [1, 3, 5, 47, 48],
 'unique_values': [[77], [100], [], [47, 48]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `drop_duplicates()`

```
df.stack().drop_duplicates(keep=False).groupby(level=1).agg(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'object_1': [77], 'object_2': [100], 'object_4': [47, 48]}
```

Comment: What about data like this - list columns (nested lists): data = {'column1':[[1, 3, 4, 5, 77],[1, 5, 100, 3, 4],[1, 5, 100, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4, 5, 5], [1, 3, 5, 47, 48]]}